# How to store status of rows in MySQL according formalization rules?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I have a table `order_executors`:

```
id | order_id | user_id | status
```

Where `order_id` and `user_id` are external keys.

The `status` columns means the state if row. It accepts `0, 1, 2`:

```
0 - default
1 - accepted
2 - canceled
```

So, I discoverated the violation of consistancy when:

```
id | order_id | user_id | status
1    1          1         1
2    1          1         2
```

In case described above I see that first user accepted a row `status = 1` then canceled this `status = 2`.

So, when business logic retrieves a data by query: `SELECT * from order_executors WHERE order_id = 1 AND status = 1` it is still work, despite user has canceled this order.

I can solve this using `SELECT * from order_executors WHERE order_id = 1 AND status = 1 AND status !== 2`.

Exactly, I can use `UPDATE` instead `INSERT` to store the current state of `status`.
But in this case I lost history of `order_executors.status`.

How to solve this design issue?

My idea is to create a new table `order_executors_history` where to store status changes:

```
id | user_id | order_id | status
```

And inside `order_executors` store the current state using UPDATE command.

Comment: So you are saying you want to keep inserting changes so you can track them right?

Comment: Yes, because I should now why user first accepted the order then canceled it

Comment: I have to say that I would put the status of the order into the order. As it can have only one status at any one time. If you want to create a change history all well an good, but keep it seperate

Comment: It is a good idea to store status in `order` table. So, maybe to add `executor_id` in `order` table near status to know who are accepted the order? What if order has some  positions and they can be accepted by some executors?

Comment: Like i said, the order can have only one status at any one time. If you want to keep a order change history then example `id | order_id | user_id | status | created_at (datetime)` for example

Comment: I got you, the `order` table contains a finish status of order. But in my case I must provide ability to assign a new executor to the order if previous rejected. How to be?

Comment: MariaDB 10.4 has [system versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) to store and access historical views of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already gave the solution.

Just update the status (or delete and insert the new row) on table **order_executors**, keeping only one row per **order_id | user_id** keys;

Create another table **order_executors_history** and when you insert/update on table **order_executors** you should make an insert into **order_executors_history**.

Both tables having the same structure.
You will have the status already ordered by your id inside table **order_executors_history**.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep history in another table with a column that indicates the date and time for changes.

but if you want to keep them in the same table, I think you can add a column with type of int(11) and default value of "**unix_timestamp(current_timestamp())**". then you can query the last status of order by selecting maximum value of the timestamp_field or by sorting query result after "where clause" in descending order and limit it to one row.